# Rails - Why does a route not exist on another route's view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to check the current URL with an if statement inside a partial. Here is the code and the problems I encountered:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>    
<%= if current_page? edit_post_path(f) %>
```

This code doesn't generate an explicit error, but the code under the if statement never works. If I don't include the `(f)` argument for `edit_post_path`, the code runs on the `edit_post_path` page but on every other page I get a missing :id error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Here is another method I tried:

```
if current_page?(:controller => 'posts', :action => 'edit')
```

That method works on the edit page, but on every other page I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts"}
```

However, I **do** have an edit action in the posts controller. So my question is: **why doesn't the edit route exist in other views?**

> Note: I solved the problem with this method:
>   `request.path.include?('edit')`

Comment: Try `<%= if current_page? edit_post_path(@post.id) %>`

Comment: `undefined method id' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: How you defined `@post` in the controller? Please post the code.

Comment: @JohnWLIV Maybe you wanted to use `post` instead of `@post`?

Comment: Hi Pavan, in the controller it's defined like this: `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`

Comment: Oh, I think I see what's going on now. I'm visiting the 'new' view, so @post is being defined like this: `@post = current_user.posts.build` and I didn't pass a variable into the partial from the 'new' view.